# Getting raw response data from with in a nsIWebProgressListener interface

Tags: xul, firefox-addon

Thanks to everyone in advance!

I have attached a nsIWebProgressListener to a xul:browser and was wondering if it was possible to get the raw response data back? Getting the headers and body would be nice, but I am really just looking for the body.

I looked into nsIRequest, which gets passed into all of the methods

(onStateChange,onProgressChange,onLocationChange,onStatusChange,onSecurityChange)

...and could not find anything, any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks again,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP requests you can use [nsITraceableChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITraceableChannel) ([here's a better page about using it](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/)). I'm not sure you can use it from a web progress listener, though.